# How to set php file as img src in extjs

Tags: php, extjs

I have a code

```
success:    function() { Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo has been uploaded.');
                        img.setSrc('image.php');
                    }
```

In image.php  `echo '/1.jpg';` But it doesn't work. Help please.

Answer (score 2):

The source of an image should be an *image*, not a piece of text containing a URL to the image.

You could change the PHP script to issue a `Location` header that redirects to the image, but you would be better off returning the URL in the response to (what I presume is) your Ajax request and using that instead of a hardcoded string.

Comment: i solve it. Instead of `echo '1.jpg'; ` I write `readfile('1.jpg');` and in js file `img.setSrc('image.php?n=1');`